# Laser Scanning Solution for Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, barcode, barcode-scanner

### Objective

I've looked at multiple libraries such as ZXing, however, all of them allow a Xamarin Forms application to scan via Camera, I am looking for a laser scanning solution and have yet to find one. Can anyone recommend one?

---

### Additional Info

- This is for reading Barcodes and QR codes but Barcodes as a priority
- To be used in android scanner guns (hand helds)

Comment: You might need to check if any SDK resources from the device manufacturer

Comment: if you have a device with a built in scanner, the device itself does the scanning and usually acts as a keyboard from an app's perspective.  You need to read the device documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

I can actually recommend a few, but it really depends on the volume you are initially going to be scanning, and whether you want to pay per year, per scan, or buy outright (which I did 5 years ago, but now switched to annual licensing).
I have had the most success with Cognex.